# Issue using C# HttpWebRequest to send request to TikTok

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webrequest, httpwebresponse, tiktok

I seem to be having issues just making a basic request to the TikTok homepage using the HttpWebRequest module in C#. Here is my code.

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://tiktok.com");

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)(request.GetResponse()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }
```

When I do this, the program hangs for a while, then I get a System.Net.WebException detailed below. I've tried setting user agents and timeouts but both don't seem to work. Any help on this would be appreciated.

> System.Net.WebException   HResult=0x80131509   Message=The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a
> receive.   Source=System   StackTrace:    at
> System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() in
> f:\dd\NDP\fx\src\net\System\Net\HttpWebRequest.cs:line 2293    at
> Live.Program.Main(String[] args) in E:\git\batch\live\Program.cs:line
> 733
>
> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
> System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(byte[], int, int) in NetworkStream.cs
>
> Inner Exception 1: IOException: Unable to read data from the transport
> connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party
> did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
> connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
>
> Inner Exception 2: SocketException: A connection attempt failed
> because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
> time, or established connection failed because connected host has
> failed to respond

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure why, but once you do

```
request.UserAgent=".NET Framework Test Client";
```

before getting the response, the problem goes away. I tried with different `User-Agent` headers but I always get the timeout. Only `.NET Framework Test Client` works for me.
I hope that helps you at least a bit.

Comment: Interesting! So that seems to work for the homepage, but then when I try with a video page URL, I get the same old issue. 

Example: https://www.tiktok.com/@taylorswift/video/7099068994640039211

Comment: I think it's not a general problem, but something on tiktok's side is configured in a way that the server doesn't respond if some headers are missing. 

When I recorded all headers that are being sent from my browser when I visit the video and re-play the request in bash, it works fine. 

What you could do is to do the same, and remove one header at a time to see when the server stops responding - you will see which headers are required.

I tried to remove `User-Agent` header and immediately I received `Access Denied` as a response.